# How to add a line in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Peter</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lois</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
```

But between the row of Peter    Griffin, and Lois Griffin, I want make a line to separate them like this:

```
_____________________
[Firstname][Lastname]
---------------------
[   Peter ][Griffin]
--------------------- <---add a line here
[   Lois  ][Griffin]
---------------------
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do this server side or client side?

Comment: @Tieson, I think he's talking about a CSS issue, so I'm gonna guess client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use CSS, something like this should work:

```
td { border-bottom: solid 1px #CCCCCC; }
```

Add padding if you want to space the words from the line a bit:

```
td { padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use css

```
table tr th, table tr td
{
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: dotted;
border-bottom-color: #666;
}
```

Comment: color will only effect text colour

Comment: @JustAnil: the `color` property's main purpose is setting the text color, but in the absence of an explicit `border-color` (or `auto`), the value from `color` will be used.

Answer (score -1):

```
tr{ border-bottom: solid 1px #999; float: left; width: 100% }
```

then for cols (lets say u have 3 cols)

```
td{width: 30%; float: left; text-indent: 10px; border-right: solid 1px #999; overflow: hidden; padding: 1%;}
```

The reason for over flow is to hide text that are longer that the field